# IHttpActionResult and Integration Testing Web API v2 Put in MS Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mstest, integration-testing

VS2013 auto generated a web api v2 controller for me based on my EF context.  I am trying to unit test the put part of the controller.  No matter what i do i can't get my asserts to check the StatusCodeResult return.  The auto generated code looks like this:

```
 // PUT api/Vendor/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutVendor(int id, Vendor vendor)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != vendor.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(vendor).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!VendorExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

My Integration test looks like this:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void PutVendor_UpdateVendorRecord_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        // Arrange
        //CleanUpVendors();

        var controller = new VendorController(ctx);
        const string vendorName = "Unit Test Company";

        // Add vendor to database
        ctx.Vendors.Add(new Vendor { Active = true, Name = vendorName });
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        var myVendor = (from v in ctx.Vendors
                        where v.Name == vendorName
                        select v).FirstOrDefault();

        // Get Newly Inserted ID
        Assert.IsNotNull(myVendor, "Vendor is Null");
        myVendor.Name = "New Name";

        // Act
        var httpActionResult = controller.PutVendor(myVendor.Id, myVendor);
        //var response = httpActionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Vendor>;
        var response = httpActionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Vendor>;

        // Assert


    }
```

Is there something wrong with my test?  What should my Asserts look like?

This assert returns true:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(httpActionResult, typeof(System.Web.Http.Results.StatusCodeResult));
```

but I don't think it is actually testing anything except that there was some kind of return.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a real database to save changes?

Comment: Yes, it is wired up through Entity Framework 6.0.1.

Comment: The only reason i am suing a real database at the moment is because i can't get Effort (.NET in memory database) to run with the new version of EF.  Once Effort is working it will create an in memory database structure for "unit testing" but right now i am just hitting it against a real, empty sql server.

Effort: https://effort.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Considering your comment about in-memory database change you are planning for, following are some examples of how you could do write tests in your scenario:

```
    PeopleController people = new PeopleController();

    // mismatched person Id returns BadRequest
    Person person = new Person();
    person.Id = 11;
    person.Name = "John updated";

    IHttpActionResult result = people.PutPerson(10, person).Result;

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(BadRequestResult));

    // ---------------------------------------------------

    // non-existing person
    Person person = new Person();
    person.Id = 1000;
    person.Name = "John updated";

    IHttpActionResult result = people.PutPerson(1000, person).Result;

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(NotFoundResult));

    // --------------------------------------------------------

    //successful update of person information and its verification
    Person person = new Person();
    person.Id = 10;
    person.Name = "John updated";

    IHttpActionResult result = people.PutPerson(10, person).Result;

    StatusCodeResult statusCodeResult = result as StatusCodeResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(statusCodeResult);
    Assert.AreEqual<HttpStatusCode>(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, statusCodeResult.StatusCode);

    //retrieve the person to see if the update happened successfully
    IHttpActionResult getPersonResult = people.GetPerson(10).Result;

    OkNegotiatedContentResult<Person> negotiatedResult = getPersonResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Person>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(negotiatedResult);
    Assert.AreEqual<string>(person.Name, negotiatedResult.Content.Name);
```

Comment: How did you take `IHttpActionResult result = people.PutPerson(1000, person).Result;`? I can't take directly the result from controller method?

Comment: you mean regarding the `.Result`...probably i didn't mention it clear...but I think I was making the assumption that if the action is returning a `Task<>`, then you can either do `.Result` to get the actual result or if your unit testing framework supports `async-await` pattern, then you can avoid it...for example, XUnit supports `async-await`..

Comment: If you return a result using ApiController.BadRequest(ModelState), then it will not cast to a BadRequestResult.  Instead, it will cast to a InvalidModelStateResult though.